# How many valence are in each molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have Benzene, Dewar Benzene, Prismane, and 1,3,5 cyclohexatriene (which looks just like benzene but with different lengths between the $\ce{C-C}$ bonds).

They are all $\ce{C_6H_6}$ chemical formula and I need to find out how many valence are in each molecule. I looked up what valence is but I'm confused if valence is the same thing as valence electrons or if valence is the amount of bonds the molecules can have. I think the amount of valence $\ce{H}$ can have is 1 but and $\ce{C}$ can have 4 so is the amount of valence 30?

i'm pretty sure the amount of valence electrons in all of them are 6.

Comment: What do you mean by " all of them "?

Comment: @M.Ibrahim for benzene, dewar benzene, prismane, and 1,3,5-cyclohexatriene

Comment: Which valence is equal to six ? carbons, hydrogens or both ?

Comment: @M.Ibrahim that's kind of my question, i dont know how to find out how many valence are in each element.

Comment: I think that it is the same in all compounds of carbon and hydrogen, C=4 and H=1, whenever the molecule is neutral and stable . How are you sure that the valence is 6 ?

Comment: @M.Ibrahim no i'm not sure the valence is 6. would the valence then be 30 if each C=4 and H=1?

Comment: Why not ?, 24 carbon electron +6 hydrogen electrons =30

Comment: A molecule doesn't have a valence (usually spelled valency). Valency is a property of atoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the answer is that they are all C6H6 compounds (sorry for the terrible image!):

[image: C6H6 picture]

As others have pointed out in the comments, it doesn't really make sense to talk about the valency of a molecule. You could say they all have the same elemental formula, but then so do around 200 other molecules (in theory).